# What styles I have to write for alignment items (react-native)

Tags: css, react-native

I have a component with TextInput and another component which is called CompanyAddress. Each company can have many addresses, therefore I have to have "plus" button.

There are container styles

```
const AppStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    inputStyle: {
        height: 40,
        width: '80%',
        borderColor: '#28c9d9',
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 20,
        fontSize: 16
    }
});
```

there is main component

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={AppStyles.container}>
        <TextInput
            autoCompleteType="name"
            placeholder="organization"
            maxLength={30}
            style={AppStyles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({name: text})} }
        />
        <CompanyAddress/>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

and there is CompanyAddress

```
class CompanyAddress extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    autoCompleteType="name"
                    placeholder="address"
                    maxLength={30}
                    style={[AppStyles.inputStyle, styles.textInput]}
                />
                <AntDesign style={styles.plus} name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
       width: '100%',
       flexDirection: 'row'
   },
   textInput: {
       width: '70%',
   },
   plus: {
       width: '30%'
   }
});
```

but my CompanyAddress now looks like that

[image]

but I want to change styles for achieve that

[image]

Comment: The only thing that you have to do is add ```justifyContent: "center"``` to your container style of ```CompanyAddress``` component.

Comment: It does not works. I have absolutely the same effect

Answer (score 0):

you can add justifyContent:center to the container and for the children alignSelf:Center 
ex:

`<View style={{justifyContent : center,flexDirection:row}}>
<View style={{alignSelf:Center}}><View>
<View style={{alignSelf:Center}}><View>
</View>`